# Route::get('(:any)',function() not working properly in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

The program is a URL shortener that I am just trying out from some tutorial ( for Laravel 3 but i am using laravel 4) and it is  supposed to give me the "some URL" as output when I click on the shortened URL.

```
   <?php

Route::get('/', function()
{   
    return View::make ('home.index');
});

Route::post('/',function(){
    $url = Input::get('url');

    // If the url is already in the table, return it
    $record=Url::whereurl($url)->first();

    if ($record) {
        //then return it 
        return View::make('home.result')
                ->with('shortened', $record->shortened);
    }

});

Route::any('{shortened}',function($shortened)   
    { echo "Everything is ok with: ".$shortened; })
        ->where('shortened', '.*');
```

Rather it is going to a error page saying

> "Not Found The requested URL /asdf was not found on this server."

I think it is a very simple error on my part. I am not sure whether they have changed the syntax or the keyword. I am not able to find any solution from the laravel docs as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following for my CMS to catch all requests with a Regex filter:

```
Route::get('{uri}', 'PublicController@init')
   ->where('uri', '.*');
```

In your case it would probably look like this:

```
Route::get('{uri}', function($uri) {
   return 'Hello, world!';
})->where('uri', '.*');
```

You can use the first one to load a method inside of a controller. The controller being `PublicController` and the method `init`. There you can handle your errors initiate any other processes based on the request.

This works really well, you can add reserved routes before ths route so it becomes the last route catching all requests that are not catched by previous routes.

Comment: Route::get('{shortened}', 'PublicController@init')
   ->where('shortened', '.*');


Route::get('{shortened}', function() {
   return 'Some url';
})->where('shortened', '.*'); Tried this code but still not getting any...i am not sure how to use the above code as well..I am a beginner...sorry...

Comment: You said 'Tried this code but still not getting any', pass $uri as parameter in the function parameters, so you get access to $uri.

Comment: @ArthurBALAGNE the `function($uri) {` was missing in the second example, it should be working like it is now.

Comment: Route::get('{shortened}',function($shortened)
{
 return'some url';
})->where('shortened', '.*'); Tried this not working...

Comment: I will try it on my server!

Comment: It works for me. You can check it if you like. `test.sidneydobber.com` I added the second solution to the default hello view. Every url request now opens the hello view.

Comment: Can you try it with `URL/index.php/asdf`. If this works mod_rewrite is not enabled.

Comment: It seems to be working fine in the `localhost/index.php/asdf`.. we are supposed to enable the mod_rewrite in the httpd.conf file right?...Yeah my bad...sorry guys for wasting all your time for so long...

Comment: Haha I ran into a lot of mod_rewrite issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 4, you do:

```
Route::get('{shortened}', function($shortened)
```

instead of

```
Route::get('(:any)',function($shortened)
```

You can read more about route parameters in Laravel 4, here: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters

Comment: Yep tried it just now...Not working as well...and also went through the docs it seems to be pretty vague...

Comment: yep i saw the typo the first time...and changed it as well...It does not seem to be working for me...:(

Comment: Are you sure, you enabled `mod_rewrite` on your Apache server?

Comment: yes have enabled it...restarted the apache server...cleared cache and everything but nothing is happening...

Comment: you were right...i did not enable the mod_rewrite...Thought it was enough if we enable it in the httpd.conf file..Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

1. Lauch Laravel

   go to you'r application root,run the command PHP artisan serve
2. Put the routing

   -Comment evrything in routing.php, add these routes:

   Route::get('/', function()
   {
       echo 'hello';
   });

   Route::any('{shortened}',function($shortened){
       echo "Evrything is ok with: ".$shortened; 
       })->where('shortened', '.*');
3. Launch you application
   -go to `http://localhost:8000/asdf`

Comment: Tried it...not working...tried both:

    Route::get('(.*)',function($shortened)
    {
        return'some url';
    });

and;

    Route::any('(.*)',function($shortened)
        {
            return'some url';
        });

Comment: My bad, i was thinking you'r a lavavel3 user, i dunno why...
This is the laravel4 way to put a regular expression:



Route::get('page/{foo}', function($foo)
{
    return "$foo.";
})->where('foo', '[A-Za-z0-9]+');

Comment: i am on the localhost, so the code will be; Route::get('/{shortened}', function($shortened){return "Some url";})->where('shortened'); is it?

Comment: Route::get('{shortened}', function($shortened){return "Some url";})->where('shortened', '[A-Za-z0-9]+');
Dont start you'r URL with leading slash, 'where' function take 2 parameters, adjust the regular expression to catch what you whant

Comment: Route::get('{shortened}',function($shortened)
{
 return'some url';
})->where('shortened', '.*'); - Tried this still not working...

Comment: what is the error ?
what is the url you'r passing ?

Comment: **Not Found

The requested URL /asdf was not found on this server.** this is the error...i am passing it through through the localhost itself...  **asdf** is the shortened value...URL being the 'localhost/asdf' where 'localhost' takes us to the 'index.php'

Comment: i've just made this: Route::any('{shortened}',function($shortened){
  echo "Evrything is ok with: ".$shortened; 
 })->where('shortened', '.*');
it worked like a charm.
Maybe the issue is deeper, is there any filter ? or group in you'r routing file ?
Are you using 'artisan serve' to launch Laravel ?

Comment: i've given the whole routing file in the above question...Just now edited it. Please let me know if there are any changes in it...

Comment: Good to hear is works for your @ArthurBALAGNE. Could you vote up if it worked, so people know it is a usefull answer? :)

Comment: i need 15 reputations to vote...i tried voting before this..But was not able to...But will surely get back and vote if i get to 15 reputations...